# Choosing one data from different queries in if else statement

Tags: php, mysql

From test.php, I have a radio input.
Different values have different queries.
When the user select a radio button, I need to run the query.
Thus selecting the data with the period chosen (month, last month).
I'm stuck! How do I call out the data from all the queries running? :(

```
<tr> 
<td><label for="period"><b>Transaction Period:</b> </label></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="period" value="current">Current Month<br>
<input type="radio" name="period" value="current_first">Last 1 Month and Current Month<br>
<input type="radio" name="period" value="current_second">Last 2 Months and Current Month</td>          
</tr>

$period = $_POST['period'];

if ($period == 'current'){
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE account_id ='$acc_id' AND user_id= '$user_id' AND MONTH(CURDATE())= MONTH(datetime)";
$result1 = mysqli_query($link, $query1) or die(mysqli_error($link));

elseif ($period = 'current_first'){
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE account_id ='$acc_id' AND user_id= '$user_id' AND datetime BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND CURRENT_DATE";
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($link));
}

else if ($period ='current_second'){
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE account_id ='$acc_id' AND user_id= '$user_id' AND datetime BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND CURRENT_DATE";
$result3 = mysqli_query($link, $query3) or die(mysqli_error($link)); 
}

else {
}

while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1/$result2/$result3)) {
                $date = $row1['datetime'];                
                $trans_code = $row1['transaction_code'];
                $reference = $row1['reference'];
                $debit = $row1['debit'];
                $credit = $row1['credit'];


echo $date;
echo $trans_code;
echo $reference;
echo $debit;
echo $credit;
```

Comment: I would set the value of the radio to 0, 1 or 2 and bind that value in a prepared statement directly. Only one query needed (you might have to check if it works correctly with 0, otherwise you'd have to modify the sql a bit...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a *closing* flower brace `}` missing after first `if` statement.

And, why don't you change your `if ... else ...` and `while ..` statements as below and try.

```
if ($period == 'current') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE account_id ='$acc_id' AND user_id= '$user_id' AND MONTH(CURDATE())= MONTH(datetime)";
} elseif ($period = 'current_first') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE account_id ='$acc_id' AND user_id= '$user_id' AND datetime BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND CURRENT_DATE";
} else if ($period ='current_second') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE account_id ='$acc_id' AND user_id= '$user_id' AND datetime BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND CURRENT_DATE";
} else {
    // what should i do?
}

$result = mysqli_query( $link, $query ) or die( mysqli_error( $link ) );
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
 // do something
 $date = $row[ 'datetime' ];
 ...

 echo $date;
 ...
} // while
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly; You want the form to be submitted when an user selects a radio button? If so, you should have to surround the input types with a form, and add: `onClick="this.form.submit();"` to the input types. So:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<tr> 
<td><label for="period"><b>Transaction Period:</b> </label></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="period" value="current" onclick="this.form.submit();">Current Month<br>
<input type="radio" name="period" value="current_first" onclick="this.form.submit();">Last 1 Month and Current Month<br>
<input type="radio" name="period" value="current_second" onclick="this.form.submit();">Last 2 Months and Current Month</td>          
</tr>
</form>
```

Oh btw, you should also have to check if `$_POST['period']` is set before executing the if and query code.